# what is this time format: XX:XX.X, and how to transfer it to usual year-month-day-hour-minute-second in Python

Tags: python, date, time, format

I have some date data like:

```
46:53.4
57:00.0
51:50.9
53:13.9
```

What is this time format? And how to transfer it to the usual year-month-day-hour-minute-second in Python?

Comment: This is only _time_ information.  There's no way to convert it to a _date_, unless you assume the date is today.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Code:

```
import datetime
#Input Date String
t = "46:53.4"

#Return a datetime corresponding to date string
dateTimeObject = datetime.datetime.strptime(t, '%M:%S.%f')
print (dateTimeObject)
```

Result:

```
1900-01-01 00:46:53.400000
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose `46:53.4` means forty-six minutes and fifty-three-point-four seconds.